# Adding a column based on condition in Polars

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Let's say I have a Polars dataframe like so:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.1, 0.9]
})
```

And now I need to add a new column where 1 or 0 is assigned depending on whether a value in column `'a'` is greater or less than some threshold. In Pandas I can do this:

```py
import numpy as np

THRESHOLD = 0.5
df['new'] = np.where(df.a > THRESHOLD, 0, 1)
```

I can also do something very similar in Polars:

```py
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.lit(np.where(df.select('a').to_numpy() > THRESHOLD, 0, 1).ravel())
    .alias('new')
)
```

This works fine but I'm sure that using NumPy here is not the best practice.

I've also tried something more like:

```py
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.lit(df.filter(pl.col('a') > THRESHOLD).select([0, 1]))
    .alias('new')
)
```

But with this syntax I keep running into the following error:

```py
DuplicateError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[47], line 5
      1 THRESHOLD = 0.5
      2 DELAY_TOLERANCE = 10
      4 df = df.with_columns(
----> 5     pl.lit(df.filter(pl.col('a') > THRESHOLD).select([0, 1]))
      6     .alias('new')
      7 )
      8 df.head()

DuplicateError: column with name 'literal' has more than one occurrences
```

So my question is two-fold: what am I doing wrong here and what is the best practice in Polars for such conditional assignments?

I did looks through docs and previous questions but couldn't find anything resembling my use-case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `select([0, 1])` doesn't really make a lot of sense Polars-wise, you're just selecting a literal. Not quite sure why that's throwing a DuplicateError as is.

Conditionals in polars are best done with [`when`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html#polars.when):

`df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col("a") > 0.5).then(0).otherwise(1).alias("b"))`

Comment: Also not sure what was causing DuplicateError, but with this solution it went away. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to pass an expression or a lambda to the `then`? In all the examples, it seems to be a hardcoded value. Something like this: `df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col("a") > 0.5).then(lambda x: x * 2)` In this case, if the value is `> 0.5`, I want the new column to have the corresponding value multiplied by 2.